# What is the risk of not upgrading WebdriverIO Version 4 to 5 or beyond?

Tags: webdriver-io

We are using webdriverIO version 4 in a quite a few frameworks where I work. While undertaking the review of one of the frameworks, the option of upgrading to version 5 was recommended. However, the framework is not the most straightforward and there will be a lot of manual fixes needed to commands in many places and the time needed for it is just not known.

Hence the question, what is the risk if we don't upgrade webdriverIO at all? Any dependencies stopping successful builds or browser version incompatibilities affecting test execution? And how soon are these likely to be realised.

Any pointers that can enable this review will be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the major risks of not updating over the long-term is Node version support dropping. As new versions of Node are released, you'll likely want to upgrade to the latest. However, since older versions of WebdriverIO won't be tested on these new Node versions, there may be incompatibilities between the two.

Apart from that, other drawbacks include:

- Missing out on important new features. For example, WebdriverIO v6 includes 'waits' by default now, so you no longer have to include so many "waitFor" commands, and your tests will be less brittle.
- Security Updates via dependencies. While not as important, considering tests aren't normally public facing, it's still nice to have the latest features available.
- Unable to make feature requests. There's a very low chance that you'd be able to get any new features added to old versions of WDIO, especially v4. This means you'd have to do it all yourself.
- Less likely to get help. If something breaks or you're in need of outside help, being on an older version will hinder any help others can provide as they'll be much less experienced with it.

I've upgraded many test suites from 4 -> 5 and while it wasn't the easiest transition, it was also very doable. Unless you have something very complicated going on, I'd put the upgrade at a week tops. It took me about a work day or two to update mine, but it wasn't the most complex code (on purpose).

Comment: Thanks, this helps to really drive the discussion on why spending this time is important, I will include on discussions. Now started to really look at the list of breaking changes and which of them are used on the framework. Once the numbers are known, should be able to make a guess of how long it is likely to take. The framework is not the most simple and also has a higher failure rate in its current state, which is why the upgrade becomes trickier as you wouldn't know why something is failing quite easily.